# How to define a variable with argument expansion

Tags: tcl

The following command runs as expected:

```
lappend {*}{arr 1}
puts [lindex $arr 0]
```

Now I am trying to make a variable of "{*}{arr 1}" like this:

```
set X "{*}{arr 1}"
lappend $X
```

But this does not work, seems $X is taken as one whole value, argument expansion is not effective.

So is it a requirement that argument expansion can not be through variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, within double quotes, `{` and `}` actually lose their meaning, so will `{*}`. Notice that `puts "{}"` and `puts {}` are different.

The closest I can think of to do what you're trying to do would be to use something like this:

```
set X {arr 1}
lappend {*}$X
```

So if you now execute `puts [lindex $arr 0]`, you get `1` as output.

Answer (score 3):

The `{*}` is a syntactic feature of Tcl (from Tcl 8.5 onwards) just as `[`…`]`, `"`…`"` or `$` is. You have to write it in the script in order for it to count as argument expansion; otherwise it's just a sequence of three characters.

If you want something like

```
set X "{*}{arr 1}"
lappend $X
```

to work, you need to pass it through `eval`:

```
set X "{*}{arr 1}"
eval lappend $X
```

Note that this then means that `X` actually contains a script fragment; this can have all sort of “interesting” consequences. Try this for size:

```
set X "{*}{arr 1};puts hiya"
eval lappend $X
```

Use of `eval` in modern Tcl is usually a sign that you're going about stuff the wrong way; the key use in old scripts was for doing things similar to that which we'd use `{*}` for now.